# Should I use ARCore Demo code or write it by myself?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

Recently I wanted to created an ARCore app and downloaded demo application. When I started to read the code I have been shocked how many lines of code there are. And I wanna know if this code is universal or I should write own for every app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the demo code as a guide/template for getting started, but eventually you'll want to move away from the demo code.